# How to use SyncTeX with Org-mode?

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode

### Background

With [SyncTeX](http://itexmac.sourceforge.net/SyncTeX.html) you can get forward and backward search between a source document and the typeset material. More specifically:

- Forward search is to jump from a particular place in the source document, e.g. a LaTeX file, to the corresponding place in the typeset material, e.g. a PDF file.
- Backward search is to jump from a particular place in the typeset material, e.g. a PDF file, to the corresponding place in the source document, e.g. a LaTeX file.

With Org-mode you can export as LaTeX and process it to PDF.

### Question

It would be useful to be able to do forward and backward search between an Org-mode file and the PDF it produces on LaTeX export. Is this possible?

As mentioned, SyncTeX already implements forward and backward search between a LaTeX file and its resulting file. So the missing link seems to be the jump between the Org-mode file and the LaTeX file it is exported as.

I found a similar question on the mailing list: [[Orgmode] synctex!! ...syncorg?](http://www.mail-archive.com/emacs-orgmode@gnu.org/msg29311.html) It got no answer involving a solution.

Comment: It is a common misperception that all and everything you can do with LaTeX should be possible by using Org-mode and exporting to LaTeX. No! Write your document in LaTeX and link into it from your Org-mode file.

Answer (score 1):

There is a recent (April 2013) [thread on the org-mode mailing list](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/69454) which has some preliminary patches.  However, reading the emails, it seems like it's a tricky problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is a more recent (depending on your frame of reference) [post from October 2013](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2013-10/msg00905.html) which has  a solution. However, I have not been successful with that code, and re-raised the issue in [this thread](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2014-02/msg00876.html).